# How to check if value (or message) is specified in protocol buffer message?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

If some field or submessage in IMessage has IsOptional property set o true, how to check if it was specified or not?

```
pbMsg.DescriptorForType.FindFieldByName("some_field_name").IsOptional == true
```

Cause if it is not, then accessing it or its subfields (or submessages) causes an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pbMsg.HasField(...)`.  Here's what the Object Browser documentation from `IMessage.HasField(...)` says about this method:

> Returns true if the given field is set. This is exactly equivalent to calling the generated "Has" property corresponding to the field.

Please note that this is using the protobuf-csharp library.

Comment: Thanks, missed that one. I had even written extension method for it previously, like: public static bool IsOptional<T>(this T pMsg, string fieldName) where T : IMessage, and forget to include it into condition check.